# How does this code work

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have just faced with the following code.

```
let rec Make_Segment list=
  match list with
  | []  ->[],[]
  | hd::tail when hd<=tail.Head -> let current,rest=Make_Segment tail
                                   hd::current,rest
  | hd::tail when hd>tail.Head -> [hd], tail

let segments= [3;4;5;5;1;2;3]

Make_Segment segments
```

It is a recursive function which always **return two lists**.
But as you can see, it always uses one parameter,which is the `list`, in its match.
So where is the first argument?

How can it works?

Comment: FYI; dereferencing `tail.Head` w/o proper pattern matching makes this function fail on input like `[3]`

Answer (score 4):

In the `match` statement, the `list` argument is being split into two values by the syntax `hd::tail`. This will match any list that's not empty (which is why a match against the empty list is also necessary), and the first item of the list will be given the name `hd`, while the rest of the list gets the name `tail`. (If the original `list` had only one item in it, then `tail` will now be an empty list).

Then when the recursive call is made, it returns a tuple of two lists, which gets *destructured* by the `let current,rest=Make_Segment tail` assignment. The first list is assigned to `current`, and the second to `rest`.